# Substituting a Button as variable AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

i'm encountering error #1046 when i want to substitute a button as a variable, any kind of help is greatly appreciated.

```
var w1:ColorTransform = new ColorTransform();
w1.color =0xCC0000; //red dark
var w2:ColorTransform = new ColorTransform(); 
w2.color = 0xB3B3B3; //Grey 

// error--------
var boxNow:Button; <= These 2 lines gives me error
boxNow = boxQ;
//---------

boxNow.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, myHover);

function myHover(event: MouseEvent):void{
    boxNow.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, myHover);
    boxNow.transform.colorTransform = w1;
    boxNow.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, myOut);
}

function myOut(event:MouseEvent):void{
    boxNow.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT,myOut);
    boxNow.transform.colorTransform = w2;
    boxNow.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, myHover);
}
```

Comment: In which line you are getting the error?

Comment: @taskinoor there i have edited my post above and those 2 lines are the error lines

Comment: can you specify what is the type of boxQ and what data itcontains

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all create a object like this

```
var boxNow:Button = new Button();
```

then chek the type of boxQ

Comment: Thanks I've solved it. yes it's concerning about the datatype, it's done now.

Comment: Glad it will help you